# Override font size on pre made validation script

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I am trying to add validation to my text boxes and have been able to do so. I am running into a problem with the font size when you type the wrong thing into the text box and don't know how to fix it. The validation script I am using is:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.js

I have included photos of what I am talking about.

[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZjDC.png)
[Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfDPz.png)

I am trying to figure out how to make that font smaller. I do not believe there is a css with this js file. Even if there is there has to be a place to override it. I will also include my script tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=tbSearchTransactionID.UniqueID %>: {
                        digits: true
                    },
                    <%=tbSearchOrderNo.UniqueID %>: {
                        digits: true
                    }
                }, messages: {
                    %=tbSearchTransactionID.UniqueID %>: {
                    digits: "Enter a number"
                }
              }
            });
        });
```

Also, this is where the text boxes sit:

```
<h3>ShopFloor Transactions</h3>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbSearchTransactionID" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Transaction ID"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbSearchOrderNo" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Order Number"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbSearchWorkCenter" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Work Center"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I bring in this big validate file. Have a small script tag running. Then have it linked to the text box names but I do not know where I can edit this font.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#form1").validate({
                        rules: {
                    <%=tbSearchTransactionID.UniqueID %>: {
                        digits: true
                    },
                    <%=tbSearchOrderNo.UniqueID %>: {
                            digits: true
                        }
                }, messages: {
                     <%=tbSearchTransactionID.UniqueID %>: {
                    digits: "<span style='font-size: 20px;'>Enter a number</span>"
                },
                     <%=tbSearchOrderNo.UniqueID %>: {
                        digits: "<span style='font-size: 20px;'>Enter a number</span>"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.